# Ubuntu Alt+AltGr+Q not working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, key-binding

I would like to know why I have this weird problem. Some sets of keybinding are not working. As example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> doesn't do anything at all. I check it with `xev` for the keystrokes and I press every key by order (first <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and then <kbd>Q</kbd>), the first two keystrokes are detected but the third one is not. This is happening only with some keys (<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> as far as I know); the others are working well.

This problem is working in a Toshiba Satellite Radius 11; meanwhile, when I test in another computer (MSI GE40), it's working perfectly well.

**Side note:** The description of the problem is based on the qwerty keyboard. 
I'm actually using a Dvorak keyboard. Thus I figured out that this problem has nothing to do with keyboard layouts, it's actually the position of the key or keycode (so, for example, the keycode 24 in qwerty is "q", in azerty is "a" and in dvorak is ".").